# why /\b[^\b]*\b/.match(" hello world ") doesn't match "hello"

Tags: ruby, regex

I am learning regular expressions in Ruby 1.9.3.

Could you tell me why

```
/\b[^\b]*\b/.match("    hello  world    ")  matched  => #<MatchData "hello  world">
```

does `[^\b]` not work? It should not across a word, right??

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `/\b\w*\b/` (`\w` = alphanumeric character).
The `\b` does not denote an actual character, but rather adds a word boundary condition to a character.

`[…]` denotes a character set. As `\b` is a flag and not a character you therefor cannot put them in a character set.

Btw, to match words you actually do not need any `\b`s. A simple `/\w+/` will do just fine.

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for a good tutorial on the proper use of `\b`.

Comment: you are right,we can use /\b\w*\b/ to match "hello", so does ^\b not means anything in [] ?,i wanna know why /\b[^\b]*\b/ match "hello  world" ,but not else..

Comment: `\bx` (with `x` being some character) simply tells the regex that there must be no alphanumeric character to the `x`'s left (or to the right in case of `x\b`). In other words: `\b` means that whatever character you type next to it must be found at a word boundary.
There is a distiction between modifier flags and actual characters in regex. I'd recommend you to read this for starters: http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/

Comment: You may also want to read this tutorial on `\b`: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html, as well as check out these resources: http://regexone.com, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, http://regexpal.com

Comment: `[\b]` means the backspace character

Comment: @robustus: Don't think so. `[\b]` matches the `b` in `foo\bar`. `[\\]` matches a backspace character. As does `\\` without the `[]`.

Comment: #Regexident - No, you are thinking of the back_slash_ (backspace is ASCII 8). Also, the expression: `/\b\w*\b/` erroneously matches the zero length position at every word boundary in the string. What you are looking for is: `/\b\w+\b/`

Comment: @ridgerunner: oh, right then. Indeed misread it for backslash. My bad.